# return statement of while loop and logic issues

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, return

I am embarrassed to ask this but I cannot seem to return the correct result for the function. Basically I can program the function to handle a solution or no solution but not both.

```
def sum_pair(l, t):
    l.sort()
    s = 0 # start index
    e = len(l) - 1 # last index

    while s < e:
        if (l[s] + l[e] == t):
            a, b = l[s], l[e]
            return a, b
        elif (l[s] + l[e] < t):
            s = + 1
        else:
            e -= 1
    return a,b # return (0,0) !no result or return (n,n) if result

l1 = [4, 3, 5, 7, 8]
target = 20 # No solution
print(sum_pair(l1, target))
```

Basically I'm trying to return (0,0) if there is no solution but I need it to return (n,n) if they sum to the target value. I would like to avoid the conditional logic if possible.

My guess is that I have a scope issue.

Thanks to anyone in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what actual problem you're having. If you didn't find a solution, why can't you just `return (0,0)`? Why do you have `a` and `b` at all?

Comment: 1. Declare and define `a = 0 and b = 0` before the while loop 2. `s += 1` not `s = + 1`

Comment: @khelwood If I change the target to 12 for example (has a solution) it still returns (0,0)

Comment: So is your actual problem that your function doesn't find solutions? What if you fix the `s = + 1` typo?

Comment: @khelwood Doesn't change the logic. If I remove the final return and have a solution then it will return from the if statement correctly. But the only way to avoid infinite while (without a solution) is to have that return. But I can't get it work that way with a solution.

Comment: @BlackList96 I tried declaring the a,b = 0,0 above the while but the if statement doesn't change the a,b (if the solution is correct)

Comment: @khelwood thank you for continuing to help me. I'm using a technique called Sorting and Two Pointers that I found here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/given-an-array-a-and-a-number-x-check-for-pair-in-a-with-sum-as-x/

Comment: I just tried your code with the problems mentioned fixed and the target 12 and it returned (4,8).

Comment: @khelwood Thank you I was experiencing something very strange. My function kept resulting in an infinite loop with the same logic but I moved it to a different file and it worked? I may not have even needed to post the question lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. No need of a and b in this problem
2. There is a typo in `s = + 1` which will be `s+=1`

```py
def sum_pair(l, t):
    l.sort()
    s = 0 # start index
    e = len(l) - 1 # last index

    while s < e:
        if l[s] + l[e] == t:
            return l[s], l[e]
         
        elif l[s] + l[e] < t:
            s += 1

        else:
            e -= 1

    return 0,0 # return (0,0) !no result or return (n,n) if result

l1 = [4, 3, 5, 7, 8]
target = 20 # No solution
print(sum_pair(l1, target))
```

This works fine for me.

Comment: Thank you I was experiencing something very strange. My function kept resulting in an infinite loop with the same logic but I moved it to a different file and it worked?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I edited your code:

```
def sum_pair(l, t):
    l.sort()
    s = 0 # start index
    e = len(l) - 1 # last index

    a, b = 0, 0 # set default return value
    while s < e:
        if (l[s] + l[e] == t):
            a, b = l[s], l[e]
            break
        elif (l[s] + l[e] < t):
            s += 1 # you typoed this line
        else:
            e -= 1
    return a, b
l1 = [4, 3, 5, 7, 8]
target = 10 # No solution
print(sum_pair(l1, target))
```

I'm not exactly sure what should happen in case there are multiple answers. This way it accepts the pair with the smallest value for `a`.

Comment: Thank you I was experiencing something very strange. My function kept resulting in an infinite loop with the same logic but I moved it to a different file and it worked.